# Playing a YouTube video or playlist on loop

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I may drive everyone around me crazy but I like to listen to the same playlist or song sometimes on loop from YouTube.

What is the best way to loop up a song or playlist until I get yelled by those around me and stop it manually?

I know of a couple ways:

- Make a custom playlist which has a lot of duplicates in it, not true looping but can be a large play list
- Copy the embed URL and append `&loop=1`, but this only works for some videos which allow embedding, and it is annoying to do this.

Is there an option I'm overlooking somewhere which exists inside the YouTube site directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [EndlessYoutube.](http://www.endlessyoutube.com/) Obviously it will still only work for videos that allow embedding but it should be less annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This is Kind of hacky, and only works for single videos, but if you're using the Firefox browser, you can get the ReloadEvery plugin ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/ ). This allows you to set a page to automatically reload at whatever interval you like. Just go to your favorite video, start watching and set the page to reload every  seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer you want, but possibly related - (**YouTube Disco**).

If you go to http://www.youtube.com/disco

YouTube asks for your first song/video keyword, then sets up an almost endless playlist of similar songs/videos (you can then add/remove/delete/shuffle songs in your playlist)

Comment: Just stumble upon this answer. Seems the feature was [removed on October 2014](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/google-to-shut-down-youtube-disco-in-october-606219). Following your link will go to YouTube user "Disco" now.

Comment: "No longer active. Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android or iPhone then create playlist and then click on auto replay icon in the playlist. There are also many websites such as youtubelooper.net which can do the job for you.

You can use Enhancer for Youtube extension available for chrome and firefox.

[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhancer-for-youtube/ponfpcnoihfmfllpaingbgckeeldkhle?hl=es) [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enhancer-for-youtube/)

Source: https://digitblogger.com/how-to-loop-youtube-videos/

Answer (score 0):

YouTube now includes this functionality natively

> ### [Loop videos or playlists on YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10788593?hl=en)
>
> #### To repeat a video:
>
> 1. Go to the watch screen of any video.
> 2. Right Click in the video player.
> 3. Click **Loop** [image] . The video will repeat continuously.
>
> #### To repeat a playlist:
>
> 1. Go to a video that's part of a playlist.
> 2. On the right, expand the playlist.
> 3. In the playlist box, click **Loop** [image] . The video will repeat continuously.